# What is the maximum number of app instances I can create simultaneously in firebase app server

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin, firebase-notifications

I have 7 projects in my firebase account, each project having 2 applications- android and IOS. I need all my 7 app instances to be created simultaneously which I can do by threading mechanisms.

```
var DemoProject = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions(){
                      Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"C:\Users\yesha.t\Desktop\WORK\Firebase-POC\fir-project-64a56-firebase-adminsdk-4dzfs-8cdf15469c.json")
                  });

var MyProject = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions() {
                      Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"C:\Users\yesha.t\Desktop\WORK\Firebase-POC\notifications-poc-fab77-firebase-adminsdk-gx7f1-49ab706663.json")
                  },"MyProject");
```

All the instances created will hit Firebase APIs, like:

- user (un)subscription to topics
- sending notification topics, etc., happening all at once.

Will these simultaneous processes cause problems with the throttling limits?

From Firebase documentation:

> The topic subscription add/remove rate is limited to 3,000 QPS per
>   project. ([Topic Message Limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#fanout_throttling))

This limit will never be reached for a single instance (will take care of this), but how do I make sure having 7 instances won't cause problems.

Appreciate some guidance here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says- the 3000 QPS rate limit for subscribe/unsubscribe operations are **project-scoped**. Same for the topic messaging (1,000 concurrent fanout messages per project).

Therefore, if you can make sure the *limit will never be reached for a single instance*- as you mentioned- you are safe from hitting rate limits.

However, note that- all applications under one project will be considered to be consuming quota from that single project.

I should also note that- how many app instances you have initialized in the admin sdk does not affect the above two rate limits. They are basically affected by following factors:

1. How many subscribe/unsubscribe requests are being sent **from android/ios apps** + via [REST api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) calls, and
2. How many topic fanouts you are sending from firebase console + admin SDK

Comment: FCM allows upto 1000 device tokens to be (un)subscribed at a time with a single API call.
Is QPS equivalent to the number device tokens subscribed per second?

Comment: I cannot confirm this but my understanding is- passing 1000 device token counts as 1000 queries. How batched requests consume from this quota is not specified in either of firebase documentation or instance id [api reference](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server)